# How to fill differences between two vectors with NaN to make equal lengths?

Tags: matlab, compare, nan, missing-data, set-difference

I am searching for a quick way to compare two vectors of different lengths and fill the shorter array's missing places with NaN values.

Example:

```
a = [2090 2091 2092 2093 2094 2095 2096 2097 2098 2099 2100 2102 2103 2104 2105 2106 2108 2109 2110 2111]

b = [2091 2092 2093 2094 2095 2096 2097 2098 2099 2100 2106]
```

I want to compare `b` to `a` and everywhere where there is a difference, I need a NaN value, so that in the end they have the same length:

```
c = [NaN 2091 2092 2093 2094 2095 2096 2097 2098 2099 2100 NaN  NaN NaN NaN 2106 NaN NaN NaN NaN]
```

I figured I can use `setdiff` to find out the differences between `a` and `b`:
`[s,idx] = setdiff(a,b)`

But I can't figure out what would be the best way to insert the NaN values into `b`, because if do e.g. `b(idx(1)) == NaN` then I overwrite what was in `b` in the first element.
Can somebody point me please to the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My assumption is, that `b` is a subset of `a`. If there are elements in `b` that are not in `a`, please provide a logic, how to handle this case.

MATLAB's [`ismember`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.ismember.html) function is your friend here (tested with Octave 5.2.0 and MATLAB Online):

```matlab
close all;
close all;
clc;

a = [2090, 2091, 2092, 2093, 2094, ...
     2095, 2096, 2097, 2098, 2099, ...
     2100, 2102, 2103, 2104, 2105, ...
     2106, 2108, 2109, 2110, 2111]

b = [2091, 2092, 2093, 2094, 2095, ...
     2096, 2097, 2098, 2099, 2100, ...
     2106]

% Get indices, where to find values from b in a     
idx = ismember(a, b)

% Create nan vector with the size of a
c = nan(size(a));

% Get correct values from the found indices
c(idx) = a(idx)
```

Output:

```
a =
   2090   2091   2092   2093   2094   2095   2096   2097   2098   2099   2100   2102   2103   2104   2105   2106   2108   2109   2110   2111

b =
   2091   2092   2093   2094   2095   2096   2097   2098   2099   2100   2106

c =
    NaN   2091   2092   2093   2094   2095   2096   2097   2098   2099   2100    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   2106    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: You might also try it as a oneliner:`a(~ismember(a,b)) = NaN`